# The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am not able to log in to my application, that's the code I use in my **AccountController** :

```
// POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        } 

        var allowed = Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password);
        if (allowed)
        {
            var result = SignInStatus.Failure;
            var user = UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username).Result;

            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                result = SignInStatus.Success;
            }

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Vous n'êtes pas autorisé à utiliser l'application");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Tentative de connexion non valide (Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect)");
            return View(model);
        }

    }
```

--> I have an error on this line :

```
var user = UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username).Result;
```

Error description :

```
[InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).]
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +5240430
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +71
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +484
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +174
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +269
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +38
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +77
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +21
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +53
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +193
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +157
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext() +502
```

I don't know why this error is there as I haven't changed the AccountController code. 
If someone has any ideas

Comment: It's not about changes in the controller, You have made changes in your model class after running the migration. so consider running the migration again.

Answer (score 0):

View Package Manager Console

Type add-migration your_migration_name

Once finished create new migration, type update-database

Run again

Answer (score 0):

I think I have to understand why but finally get it working !
Problem was effectively in my identity model :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("T_USER").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        }
    }
```

I had deleted yesterday this line to clean my code, just add it again and everything went fine :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("T_USER").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
```

Because I thought I didn't need IdentityUser anymore, as I use ApplicationUser :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public  string GetFullName(System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal usr)
        {
            var fullNameClaim = ((ClaimsIdentity)usr.Identity).FindFirst("FullName");
            if (fullNameClaim != null)
                return fullNameClaim.Value;

            return "";
        }
    }
```

Edit: I precise I'm not using code first approach, updates are made in the database and after I synchronize the edmx